# Retrospective power analyis of lmer for sample size

Tags: sample-size, lme4-nlme, statistical-power

I'm an MSc student doing an assignment where I am asked to analyze and write up a report on a dataset on environmental enrichment in zebra finches. Among other things we are being asked to do a retrospective power analysis too see whether the number of birds used was justified.

For the initial power analysis I used the `pwr.anova.test()` function from the `pwr` package, and used Cohen's standard d values to fill in f. For the retrospective I suspect they want me to find the effect of my model, plot the value into a power analysis and see what number of observations I would in fact have needed. They specifically say we do not need to use anything more sophisticated than what we learned in class (which was basically `power.t.test()`).

For modeling we are using `lme4`, and I have no idea how to extract the effect size from that. I have looked at similar questions and not been able to make much of it.

We're 15 reasonably smart people and all equally confused. Help?

For information:
Individual birds were re-used for six trials each in a total of 30 trials (100 birds, 600 observations). My final model goes like this:

```
fear2 <- lmer(data = acoustic, FEAR ~ SOUND*SEX + (1|BIRD) + (1|TRIAL))
```

FEAR is a frequency of behaviour in percentages, and SOUND is categorical with three levels.

Comment: You may want to draw your supervisor's attention to the fact that "post hoc power analysis" based on observed effect sizes is useless. [See here.](http://www.vims.edu/people/hoenig_jm/pubs/hoenig2.pdf)

Comment: We know that. We're supposed to do it so that we can discuss sample size from a 3Rs perspective, ie whether the use of that many animals was justified (I'm doing animal welfare science).